# Database looping algorithm driving me crazy

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

This is a C# Windows application.

I have 2 datatables in memory, I'll call them `GoodTable` and `BadTable`. The number of rows and columns are identical, so are the column names. All of the rows in `BadTable` have bad data in most columns. I need to loop through all rows in `BadTable` and replace the data in all columns with the data from the matching row in `GoodTable`. However there are 2 column names that I need to skip when doing the updates, I'll call them `SkipColumn1` and `SkipColumn2`.

I've tried numerous versions of nested `foreach` loops with nested for loops to keep track of column count, and my results are just all over the place. If there are any database looping ninjas out there I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there a (valid) ID column? And why not use a simple SQL statement?

Comment: Take a 5 minute break. Simplify and breakdown your problem and slowly recreate a solution.

Comment: How do you identify a row? You can loop through all the rows in the "Good" table (as if the row isn't in Good Table then you can't update anything in Bad), and select the corresponding DataRow from the "Bad" table using table.Select. Once you have the row, you can just update the columns you want, by looping through the table.Columns collection, and ignoring the two columns with the name you don't want.

Comment: You seem to have tried something already. Mind showing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I'm accepting because it's the cleanest and most simple in my opinion.

```
for (var i = 0; i < GoodDT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < GoodDT.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        if (BadDT.Columns[x].ColumnName != "skip1" && BadDT.Columns[x].ColumnName != "skip2")
        {
            BadDT.Rows[i][x] = GoodDT.Rows[i][x];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        var goodTable = new DataTable();
        var badTable = new DataTable();

        // some initialization code (add columns, fill with data)...

        var columnNames = goodTable
            .Columns
            .Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Where(column => column.ColumnName != "SkipColumn1" && column.ColumnName != "SkipColumn2")
            .Select(column => column.ColumnName)
            .ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < goodTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
            {
                badTable.Rows[i][columnName] = goodTable.Rows[i][columnName];
            }
        }
```

Comment: One issue with this is that it assumes that the rows are in the same order in both tables. Otherwise, agree.

Comment: @dash: yes, you're right. I don't know, why I've supposed this. :) On the other hand, OP said nothing about, how he identifies rows...